# SQL Random 10 Percent based on 2 other fields

Tags: sql

I have reviewed the other posts here with no luck on finding a solution to get a random 10 percent of records based on 2 other fields.  For example my table contains ID, Date and User.  I want to flag 10 percent of the records for each user for each day.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum * 10 <= cnt then 'Y' else 'N' end) as flag
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user, date order by newid()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by user, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

You don't actually need the subquery.  It is just to make it a bit easier to follow, so:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user, date order by newid()) * 10 <= count(*) over (partition by user, date)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: That worked thanks for your help that was much easier than what I was trying to do.